# What can I do with a Bluetooth connection between Windows Phone and Surface Pro?

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, microsoft-surface, windows-phone

I have both an `HTC Windows Phone 8x` and a `Surface Pro`, each of course with Windows 8. Both of them I log in using my same Microsoft Live account. I can manage to get my phone connected to the surface via Bluetooth, however once I do, I get no options and it just disconnects a few seconds later. I would assume that connecting these would allow me to do things like share media, etc.

Since they automatically disconnect without giving me any options, what actually is the significance in allowing the two to connect in the first place?